# How to run/debug ahk (AutoHotScripts) scripts using gVim, Vim?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

How to execute ahk (AutoHotScripts) scripts using gVim?

Let say I have interpreter:

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" /ErrorStdOut "d:\ahk\myscript.ahk" 2>"Syntax-Error Log.txt"
```

While I am in normal mode in gVim I press `leader s`. Screen divides into two windows. New window with Error Stream shows at the bottom. Similar to every IDE behaviour when you run/debug program.

Window focus should stay at the window with ahk script. If everything is OK, then ahk script is executed.

Comment: Bit late now, but take a look at `:help 30.1`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do partial solution, but still there is problem with, nesting errorlog windows, and cmd.exe that hangs after execution.

`noremap <leader>s :!"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" /ErrorStdOut
\ %:p 2>"errorlog.txt"<CR> :sp errorlog.txt<CR><C-W>J<CR> :resize 5<CR>`

Comment: Try using: `:!start` instead of just `:!` to suppress the cmd.exe window.